# Macro to insert a formula and drag it down

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to split the contents of a column into various columns. The column has content that looks like this:

```
3-BW16569*AW34586*AW34587
3- LVA18140 & LVA19222
3-LVA22841
3- JDSC RELOAD
3 - LV1 TO JDSC 6/21
3- LVU21690
3-LVA19520*LVU21739
3- R241974/R241974
```

The column is not in a particular format but always has different symbols between the elements to separate them. Can a macro code help with this or a excel function. Thank you!

Comment: how would you like to see them in separate columns?

Comment: For example in row 1: Column1: 3, Column2:BW16569, Column3:AW34586, Column4:AW34587. Similarly for other rows.

Answer (score -1):

All thanks to [alainbryden](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/1480/How-to-Split-a-String-with-Multiple-Delimiters-in-VBA.html) for the function `SplitMultiDelims()` . . don't change it, foo() may help you through in how to use it in your problem...

[image: See This Picture]

```
     Sub foo()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sizeArr, index As Integer
Dim Arr() As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim str As String
Dim dilimiters As String
Dim str1 As String
dilimiters = " -*" ' provide all of them


str = "3-BW16569*AW34586*AW34587" ' read the string
'str = ws.Cells(1, 1).Value
Debug.Print str


Arr = SplitMultiDelims(str, dilimiters) ' delimit

sizeArr = UBound(Arr) ' get no of different strings you have

For index = 0 To sizeArr Step 1

str1 = Arr(index) ' get the string
Debug.Print str1

' now paste where evere you want

Next




End Sub


    Function SplitMultiDelims(ByRef Text As String, ByRef DelimChars As String, _
            Optional ByVal IgnoreConsecutiveDelimiters As Boolean = False, _
            Optional ByVal Limit As Long = -1) As String()
        Dim ElemStart As Long, N As Long, M As Long, Elements As Long
        Dim lDelims As Long, lText As Long
        Dim Arr() As String

        lText = Len(Text)
        lDelims = Len(DelimChars)
        If lDelims = 0 Or lText = 0 Or Limit = 1 Then
            ReDim Arr(0 To 0)
            Arr(0) = Text
            SplitMultiDelims = Arr
            Exit Function
        End If
        ReDim Arr(0 To IIf(Limit = -1, lText - 1, Limit))

        Elements = 0: ElemStart = 1
        For N = 1 To lText
            If InStr(DelimChars, Mid(Text, N, 1)) Then
                Arr(Elements) = Mid(Text, ElemStart, N - ElemStart)
                If IgnoreConsecutiveDelimiters Then
                    If Len(Arr(Elements)) > 0 Then Elements = Elements + 1
                Else
                    Elements = Elements + 1
                End If
                ElemStart = N + 1
                If Elements + 1 = Limit Then Exit For
            End If
        Next N
        'Get the last token terminated by the end of the string into the array
        If ElemStart <= lText Then Arr(Elements) = Mid(Text, ElemStart)
        'Since the end of string counts as the terminating delimiter, if the last character
        'was also a delimiter, we treat the two as consecutive, and so ignore the last elemnent
        If IgnoreConsecutiveDelimiters Then If Len(Arr(Elements)) = 0 Then Elements = Elements - 1

        ReDim Preserve Arr(0 To Elements) 'Chop off unused array elements
        SplitMultiDelims = Arr
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is however not working for me. How exactly did you use it?

Comment: @AshleyLarson see the attached image, I tested all of them one by one, and it worked fine for me, you need to care on choosing delimiters other I think the problem is solved